# TextField ESCAPE Keycode not caught

Tags: javafx, event-handling, keycode

I'm trying to catch an ESCAPE key press in a textfield.
I was expecting to put a simple event listener (or even an event filter) to the textfield. But nothing works.
It seems all key events are caught, except the ESCAPE key I 'm waiting for.

Can you provide any help please, 
Thanks in advance

PS: the following bunch of code explains how I proceed.

```
public class KeyEventSample extends Application {
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public KeyEventSample() {super();}

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        final TextField textField = new TextField();
        final TextArea textArea = new TextArea();

        textField.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, e -> {
            if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE)
                textArea.appendText("ESCAPE");
            else if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER)
                textArea.appendText("ENTER");
            else
                textArea.appendText("->"+e.getCode().toString());
        });

        final BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        borderPane.setCenter(textField);
        borderPane.setBottom(textArea);

        final Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane, 300, 300);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code worked just fine for me, as is. I pressed Escape, with focus on the text field, and the text "ESCAPE" appeared in the text area below. What JDK version and OS are you running on?

Comment: I'm working with a macosx 10.12.2, with jdk1.8.0_66.jdk

Comment: I also have Mac OS X 10.12.2. I ran with jdk 1.8.0_60, 1.8.0_71, 1.8.0_92, 1.8.0_111 and it worked fine on all of those. It will be hard to assess the issue if it's not reproducible. Maybe someone else can reproduce it.

Comment: I've just updated the code in order to display every change. All the keys are caught except ESCAPE, EJECT and FN functions. (I've got a macbookpro). For your information my real project reacts exactly in the same way that this excerpt.

Comment: I *still* get `ESCAPE`. I don't get `EJECT` or `FN` (which don't surprise me). I even downloaded an archive version of JDK 1.8.0_66 and tested that. I checked with both my MacBook Pro native keyboard and an attached USB keyboard... Presumably your escape key works in other applications? Not sure I have any other suggestions for you.

Comment: I feel so confused, I apparently have a key issue that I did not notice earlier (I swap from the native keyboard to a wireless one).  1.5 evenings lost for such a simple thing. Thank you so much JAMES_D for your help.

Comment: Ugh. Sorry for your lost time. At least you know your code is good. "Once you eliminate the impossible, whatever remains, no matter how improbable, must be the truth."